# EF get Keyvalues of added objects

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Is it possible to get the entity keyvalues of added objects?

The keyvalues are set after context.SaveChanges(). But unfortunately after context.SaveChanges the EntityState.Added is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the primary key of an entity thats been added to the context? If so you can just access it directly following the SaveChanges(). By calling the entity object's primary key property.

Ie.

```
context.AddToMyTable(entity);
context.SaveChanges();
int primaryKey = entity.Id;
```

The entity object should get updated after you save the changes.

Comment: i am speaking of getting the entity keys only of the *added* objects